# Search multi word strings in a single word list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of words that I store in a set() for fast lookups such as:

```
one
two
three
```

I want to search if a given string (i.e. 'one three') can be written by using the words in the dictionary (it would be a multiword anagram)
My first idea to accomplish this would be to create a new wordlist such as:

```
one
two
three
one two
one three
two three
```

And to do a lookup for the matching string, I see some flaws with this approach:

- Generated wordlist will be very big and huge if I decide to create three word combinations.
- Best way to create the wordlist

At the end the solution proposed (thanks @all) is to split the the multiword string instead and look if each member is in the wordlist.

Comment: Since the problem is simply to find whether each word in your given phrase appears in the dictionary, this is a trivial (split, lookup) sequence.

Comment: Can this question be reopened? I already reworded the title to more concise, included some more reasoning on the solutions apported, included one of the replies, and also got positively voted by more people than downvoted. Before asking the question I couldn't find a simlar one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your words are a set, lookup is constant time. There's no need to make all permutation of the words. With a word list in a set you can split the string into words and check the all are in the set:

```
words = {'one', 'two','three'}

sentence = "one two two three"
all(s in words for s in sentence.split())  
# True

sentence = "one two two three four"
all(s in words for s in sentence.split())
# False
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks so simple this way, definitely I was  overcomplicating the scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

If you store all combinations of words in the set, the set is likely to grow exponentially without providing much value. To check if a particular string can be made using words from the set, we should check each word in the string at runtime:

```
def words_in_set(my_str, words_set):
    words = my_str.split()
    return all(word in words_set for word in words)
```